# If $\ \frac{b_n}{a_n}\ \overset{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}\ \alpha\neq0,\ $ then $\sum a_n\ $ converges $\ \iff\ \sum b_n\ $ converges?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-writing

I'm stuck on an easy question because... I don't know. I'm old? Anyway, it's annoying me, because I usually don't find these questions too difficult, and I'm pretty sure I've seen it before.

If $\ a_n,\ b_n\in\mathbb{R}\ $ with $\ a_n\neq0\ \forall n\in\mathbb{N},\ $ and $\ \frac{b_n}{a_n}\ \overset{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}\ \alpha\neq0,\ $ then $\ \displaystyle\sum a_n\ $ converges $\ \iff\ \displaystyle\sum b_n\ $ converges

No way this can be false, since at some point $\ b_n\ $ will be tied relatively closely to $\ \alpha a_n,\ $ ( i.e. $\ b_n\ $ will be relatively far away from $\ 0\ $ compared with the distance from  $\ b_n\ $ to  $\ \alpha a_n. )\ $ I would like to solve it all in one go, i.e. avoiding splitting into cases like $\ \alpha < 0\ $ and then $\ \alpha > 0,\ $ because due to "$\ b_n\ $ will be bounded relatively closely to $\ \alpha a_n$", this seems to me like it should be straightforward.

I've tried a few avenues to go down with regards to a proof: mainly starting from $\ \varepsilon-n\ $ definitions of convergence, but before I spend more time on this, *I just want to check if I'm missing something really obvious*.

Comment: What are you assuming about the $a_n$'s and the $b_n$'s?

Comment: That they are real numbers. Although probably this can be extended to complex numbers? But the intention was with real numbers.

Comment: If $a_n$, $b_n$, and $\alpha$ are positive, then this statement is known as the [Limit comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test)

Comment: [Here](https://www.disei.unifi.it/upload/sub/pubblicazioni/repec/flo/workingpapers/storicodimad/2003/dimadwp2003-01.pdf) you can find an example showing that it is false in general (Example 7, PAge 6).
[Here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/10.4169/amer.math.monthly.122.9.893) a similar one but in American MAthematical Monthly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe because you are doing another problem so your brain is not well versed with this kind of question.

---

**Counter example**

$a_n= \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}$, $b_n= \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}+\frac{1}{n}$

Comment: Yes, I did not think of that example. Well done.